# What's the splitting field of $x^3 - 1$ in $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What's the splitting field of $x^3 - 1$ in $\Bbb Q$?

I see that the roots are $1, \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$, and $\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}$, which would imply that the splitting field should be $\Bbb Q\left(1, \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}, \frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)$, but the book is saying that it's just $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$?  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your field and the book's field are the same field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roots of the equation are $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2},\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2},1$. Out of these, $1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ already. Now, suppose we  adjoin $\sqrt{-3}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, we see that:
$$
\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2} = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-3}, \frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2} = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-3}
$$

Hence, each of the roots, are in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, because they are a linear combination of a rational number and $\sqrt{-3}$. Hence, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ contains all the roots of $x^3-1=0$ and hence is the splitting field of the polynomial (any strictly smaller field would have to be of degree $1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, but then $\mathbb{Q}$ does not contain the roots of $x^3-1$).

Comment: On the $5$th line, do you mean $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$?

Comment: I do, @OliverG. Thank you for pointing out. Just to clarify your doubt, while adjoining elements, you should make sure that they are "linearly dependent", which is to say : no non-zero linear combination of these quantities sums  to zero. In your explanation, you wrote $\mathbb{Q}(1,\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{-3}}{2})$. Do you see which two of these have a linear combination summing to zero? In that case, mentioning both of them  is a redundancy: you can mention just one of them. Therefore, your answer is correct, but it could have been more succinct, as has happened here.

Comment: You forgot those minus signs again, астон! (Although it doesn't really matter in this case, because the field is the same.)